# How to check the K8s / K3s pod status programmatically with containerd runtime?

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, k3s, containerd

I am wondering whether there is a provision to check the pod status in k8s environment with containerd as runtime programmatically.

I tried looking at https://github.com/containerd/containerd and https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools but both don't seem to have any means to get the precise status of each pod.

Cri-tools / crictl can give whether the pod is ready or not ready ( but that doesn't consider whether the readiness checks are passing behind the scenes are not ).

Below is the code that checks health status of docker container in docker world

**Question**

- Is it possible to know the status of each pod running in k8s/k3s in GOlang client libraries like shown below when containerd is runtime?

Any inputs are much appreciated. Thank you.

```golang
// Create a docker client
cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    filteredContainers, err := cli.ContainerList(ctx, types.ContainerListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
if len(filteredContainers) < 1 {
        return false, errors.New("No other docker containers are up")
}

// inspect each container ..
inspectResult, err := cli.ContainerInspect(ctx, containerID)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    } else {
        if inspectResult.State.Health != nil {
            // Check Health Status in available container
            if inspectResult.State.Health.Status == "healthy" {
                return true, nil
            }
        } 
    }
    return false, nil
```

Comment: I'd probably use the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) for this; that will be independent of the underlying container runtime, and will work even if you're not physically on one of the cluster nodes.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you , but am looking to do this programatically in GO as my client application that runs in collocated manner needs this information without using k8s api server & directly relying on container runtime.

Comment: Containerd doesn't know anything about pods, that's a kubernetes abstraction. Similarly container health checks also only exist in kubernetes.

Comment: That's indeed right , wondering whether any hooks to get that info from container runtime.